# Canvas создание нескольких счетчиков

Tags: javascript, canvas, counter

Подскажите, как создать несколько холстов со счетчиками которые работали по логике одной функции. Приведу пример

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var currency = '\u20B4 '; /// uah
  var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('canvas-counter');
  var canvasesLenght = canvas.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < canvasesLenght; i++) {
    var ctx = canvas[i].getContext('2d');
  }

  canvas.width = 275;
  canvas.height = 125;

  ctx.font = "700 28px Roboto, sans-serif";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';

  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = 5;
  ctx.shadowBlur = 8;

  var counter = 0;

  /// Random number
  function randomInteger(min, max) {
    var rand = min + Math.random() * (max - min);
    rand = Math.round(rand);
    return rand;
  }

  function JackPot(number, currentShadow) {
    this.number = number;
    this.currentShadow = currentShadow;
  }


  var myJackPotRed = new JackPot(121, "rgba(122, 7, 5, .85)"); /// red
  var myJackPotDiamond = new JackPot(2233, "rgba(122, 7, 5, .85)"); /// diamond
  var myJackPotGold = new JackPot(33324, "rgba(122, 7, 5, .85)"); /// gold
  var myJackPotSilver = new JackPot(423333, "rgba(122, 7, 5, .85)"); /// silver


  function createCounter(myJackPot) {
    ctx.shadowColor = myJackPot.currentShadow;
    var currentNumber = myJackPot.number;

    redraw();

    function redraw() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      counter = randomInteger(2, 10);

      currentNumber = currentNumber + counter;
      ctx.fillText(currency + currentNumber, 125, 65);
      return currentNumber
    }

    setInterval(redraw, 1000);
  }

  createCounter(myJackPotRed);
  createCounter(myJackPotDiamond);
  createCounter(myJackPotGold);
  createCounter(myJackPotSilver);

}
```

```css
.canvas-counter {
  width: 275px;
  height: 125px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-right: 3.4%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="jackpots-winns">
  <canvas class="canvas-counter canvas-counter-red"></canvas>
  <canvas class="canvas-counter canvas-counter-diamond"></canvas>
  <canvas class="canvas-counter canvas-counter-gold"></canvas>
  <canvas class="canvas-counter canvas-counter-silver"></canvas>
</div>
```

Я не понимаю, как инициализировать все 4 счетчика, а не последний, и что б каждый начинал отсчет со своего числа ?

Answer (score 2):

Исправил Ваш код, оставив его максимально похожим на оригинал, но его все равно надо рефакторить =)

Ваша ошибка была в том, что таймер и общался только с последней канвой из списка

самое простое решение - передать канву в виде аргумента

```
 function createCounter(myJackPot, canvas)
```

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var currency = '\u20B4 '; /// uah
  var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('canvas-counter');
  
  function randomInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.round(min + Math.random() * (max - min));
  }

  function JackPot(number, currentShadow) {
    this.number = number;
    this.currentShadow = currentShadow;
  }

  var myJackPotRed = new JackPot(121, "rgba(122, 7, 5, .85)"); /// red
  var myJackPotDiamond = new JackPot(2233, "rgba(122, 7, 5, .85)"); /// diamond
  var myJackPotGold = new JackPot(33324, "rgba(122, 7, 5, .85)"); /// gold
  var myJackPotSilver = new JackPot(423333, "rgba(122, 7, 5, .85)"); /// silver

  function createCounter(myJackPot, canvas) {
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = 275;
    canvas.height = 125;
    
    ctx.font = "700 28px Roboto, sans-serif";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';

    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 5;
    ctx.shadowBlur = 8;
    
    var counter = 0;
    ctx.shadowColor = myJackPot.currentShadow;
    var currentNumber = myJackPot.number;

    canvas._redraw = redraw;
    redraw();
    function redraw() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      counter = randomInteger(2, 10);
      currentNumber = currentNumber + counter;
      ctx.fillText(currency + currentNumber, 125, 65);
      return currentNumber
    }
  }

  createCounter(myJackPotRed,  canvas[0]);
  createCounter(myJackPotDiamond, canvas[1]);
  createCounter(myJackPotGold,  canvas[2]);
  createCounter(myJackPotSilver,  canvas[3]);
  
  setInterval(() => [...canvas].forEach(c => c._redraw()), 1000);

}
```

```css
.canvas-counter {
  width: 275px;
  height: 125px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-right: 3.4%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="jackpots-winns">
  <canvas class="canvas-counter canvas-counter-red"></canvas>
  <canvas class="canvas-counter canvas-counter-diamond"></canvas>
  <canvas class="canvas-counter canvas-counter-gold"></canvas>
  <canvas class="canvas-counter canvas-counter-silver"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Похожие примеры можно найти [тут](http://learn.javascript.ru/closures)

Создадим функцию `makeCounter`, которая будет являться конструктором счетчика. Если передать в неё параметр - счетчик будет стартовать с переданного значения. По умолчанию (если вызвать `makeCounter` без параметра) счетчик будет стартовать с единицы.

```
function makeCounter(initVal) {
  function counter() {
    return counter.currentCount++;
  };
  counter.currentCount = initVal || 1;

  return counter;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
const counter1 = makeCounter();
console.log(counter1()); // 1
console.log(counter1()); // 2
console.log(counter1()); // 3

const counter2 = makeCounter();
console.log(counter2()); // 1
console.log(counter2()); // 2
```